# How to download sections from youtube videos from command line with bad internet

Tags: ffmpeg, video, download, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I want to download certain sections from a youtube stream, currently I'm using this command to get the job done:

```
yt-dlp --download-sections "*30:15-1:40:25" $LINK
```

the problem is that if the connection is lost just for a few minutes, the download has to start all over again, I'm also aware of this command:

```
youtube-dl --youtube-skip-dash-manifest -g "URL"
```

The two url outputs gets saved into urls[] in python and:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss "00:41:10" -i urls[0] -ss "00:41:10" -i urls[1] -map 0:v -map 1:a -ss 5 -t  "01:50:11" -c:v libx265 -c:a aac ../Clips/stream.mkv
```

That also has the problem of losing all downloaded if the connection is lost for a few minutes

I can't download the whole stream because it would take forever, so simply using:

```
youtube-dl $LINK
```

or

```
yt-dlp $LINK
```

it's not an option even though they offer reconnecting

Comment: Use JDowloader. It allows reconnecting.

Comment: Can be automated? I need to do it with many streams without me being present

Comment: It is automated by default. If the connection is lost it'll start a countdown timer and reconnect automatically until finished.

Comment: I mean, can I put on a command line to download a portion of the stream with JDownloader?

Comment: As the "J" in JDownloader suggest this is JAVA software with a GUI so, forget command line. Open the software, add as many videos to download, let it do its thing, that's all.

Comment: That won't work for me, I need to be able to automate it, ej, new stream comes out, a script add the link and another script downloads  a portion of it

Comment: If so then you should perhaps fix your internet service. I merely suggested a software that works great for this situations because it reconnects automatically and allows partial downloads, i.e., it won't restart the download from the beginning but from the point it stopped. And this suggestion was posted as a comment, not an answer , because I don't know your specific needs when violating the YouTube's ToS, but it feels you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: yeah, fixing my internet would solve the issue either by being reliable and downloading partially or being fast and downloading the full stream, but thats not possible for the foreseeable future, and as of now I'm stuck with a solution that takes me hours every month

Comment: @AlejandroGarcia would it be an option to get a cheap VPS, download and convert the videos on it and then download it to your local machine?

Comment: it could be a solution

Answer (score 1):

There are some (arguably) better forms of the ffmpeg command/arguments that could be used - although, admittedly, this *still* doesn't address the reconnection issue.

From Reddit - [How to download specific parts of a livestream?](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubedl/comments/11wn9x7/comment/jd001mx/?context=3),

> ```
> ffmpeg -ss 11:23:32 -to 12:25:00 -i $(yt-dlp -g https://youtube.com/watch?v=EXAMPLE) ./my-clip.mp4
> ```
>
> Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBtbsfPrkcc
>
> ...
>
> On linux you can schedule a command with the at command, cron, or
> systemd timer. I'm sure there's a way to schedule a command on windows
> but I don't know how.
>
> If you pass `-t hh:mm:ss` instead of `-to hh:mm:ss` to `ffmpeg`, it
> will stop after the duration specified elapses instead of starting at
> a timestamp specified.
>
> Altogether, the command could look like this
>
> ```
> echo 'ffmpeg -y -t 01:00:00 -i $(yt-dlp -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JUHxDBMAXE) clip.ts' | at 21:00
> ```

A further note:

> Windows used to have a command-line `at.exe` command, but it is depreciated on newer versions. It has been replaced with `schtasks.exe`. The Windows GUI for it is `taskschd.msc`

Comment: ffmpeg -ss 2:43:16 -to 2:47:29 -i $(yt-dlp -f 22 -g $LINK) ./my-clip2.mp4